# PostgreSQL: Create index for boolean column

Tags: postgresql, boolean, database-indexes

I have a table that has one boolean column.

```
productid integer
isactive boolean
```

When I execute the query

```
SELECT productid   
    FROM 
    product  
    WHERE ispublish
    LIMIT 15 OFFSET  0
```

[image]

After that, I created an index for the `ispublish` column:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_product_ispublish ON product USING btree (ispublish)
```

and re-execute

```
SELECT productid   
       FROM 
       product  
       WHERE ispublish
       LIMIT 15 OFFSET  0
```

The result:

[image]

=> No difference

I've been tried the following, but the results are the same:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_product_ispublish ON product USING btree (ispublish)

CREATE INDEX idx_product_ispublish ON product USING btree (ispublish)

CREATE INDEX idx_product_ispublish ON product (ispublish) WHERE ispublish is TRUE
```

Who can explain that to me?

Comment: Try `CREATE INDEX ... ON product (productid) WHERE ispublish` -- this should trigger index-only scans (for your specific query; at least most of the time: this depends on how many rows you have f.ex.). -- Predicates in partial indexes' `WHERE` clause **must** match your queries' predicates in order to be used. `WHERE ispublish`, `WHERE ispublish = TRUE` and `WHERE ispublish IS TRUE` are 3 different predicates.

Answer (score 178):

PostgreSQL will use an index only if it thinks it will be cheaper that way.
An index on a `boolean` column, which can only take two possible values, will almost never be used, because it is cheaper to sequentially read the whole table than to use random I/O on the index and the table if a high percantage of the table has to be retrieved.

An index on a `boolean` column is only useful

1. in data warehouse scenarios, where it can be combined with other indexes via a *bitmap index scan*.
2. if only a small fraction of the table has the value `TRUE` (or `FALSE` for that matter). In this case it is best to create a *partial index* like

   ```
    CREATE INDEX ON mytab((1)) WHERE boolcolumn;
   ```

   That indexed value is the constant 1 (index expressions that are not column references or look like a function call have to be in an extra pair of parentheses for syntactical reasons). The only relevant part about this index is its `WHERE` condition. The constant 1 is there just because *something* has to be indexed. If you have a (small) column that you can use instead, do it.

Comment: would mytab((true)) be smaller than mytab((1)) ?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: This is excellent for soft deletes. I was running a fairly complex query on a 15M row table with just 50k active rows.  Adding this index reduced query time from 1m 23s, down to 4s.