# How to set partial index with npgsql?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql, ef-core-3.1

I have very big table `Pushes` that contains `Sent` field (boolean). I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972726/postgres-sql-create-index-for-boolean-column/42972924). Now I know that I need partial index. Because I'm going to select all rows that have `Sent` as true (~ 30% from whole table). After this, I'm going to find special row that I need by some conditions. 
I hope to have a growth of performance after setting the index. I saw this [issue](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/286). But I don't understand how to set partial index for current npgsql version. I use .Net Core 3.1, all packages have the last version. Current npgsql version is `3.1.1.2`. 
I can't find `.HasIndexPartial` method. Was it removed?

I can call only

```
// indexes
modelBuilder.Entity<Push>()
    .HasIndex(x => x.Sent);
```

But how I can say here that it's partial index?

Comment: Looking at [this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/286), it looks like you use syntax like `b.HasIndex(x => x.Sent).HasFilter(/* filter here */);`

Comment: It seems you are right. I didn't pay attention( Thank you!

Comment: @stuartd If you posted that as an answer, I'd upvote. It works!