# Indexing the condition of a partial index in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, partial-index

I'm trying to reason about how [Postgres partial indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/indexes-partial.html) are stored inside Postgres. Suppose I create an index like this

```
CREATE INDEX orders_unbilled_index ON orders (order_nr)
WHERE billed is not true
```

in order to quickly run a query like

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE billed is not true AND order_nr > 1000000
```

Postgres obviously stores an index on `order_nr` built over a subset of the `orders` table as  defined by the conditional expression `billed is not true`. However, I have a couple of questions related to this:

1. Does Postgres store another index internally on `billed is not true` to quickly find the rows associated with the partial index?
2. If (1) is not the case, would it then make the query above run faster if I made a separate index on `billed is not true`? (assuming a large table and few rows with `billed is true`)

**EDIT:** My example query based on the docs is not the best due to [how boolean indexes are rarely used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42972924/1452257), but please consider my questions in the context of any conditional expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A b-tree index can be thought of an ordered list of index entries, each with a pointer to a row in the table.

In a partial index, the list is just smaller: there are only index entries for rows that meet the condition.

If you have the index condition in your `WHERE` clause, PostgreSQL knows it can use the index and doesn't have to check the index condition, because it will be satisfied automatically.

So:

1. No, any row found via the index will automatically satisfy the index condition, so using the index is enough to make sure it is satisfied.
2. No, an [index on a boolean column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42972726/6464308) will not be used, because it would not be cheaper than this partial index, and the partial index can be used to check the condition on `order_nr` as well.

   It is actually the other way around: the partial index could well be used for queries that only have the `boolean` column in the `WHERE` condition, if there are few enough rows that satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that Postgres will simply build an index which can only be used to lookup records which have `billed` as not being true.  That is, the resulting B-tree would be indexed by the `order_nr`, but would only link back to the original table when `billed` be false.

If you keep reading the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/indexes-partial.html), immediately after what you cited, you will find the following query as an example:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE billed is not true AND amount > 5000.00;
```

It is the case that Postgres *might* even choose to use the index you defined on the above query.  It can use your index to satisfy this query by scanning the entire index.  If there are a relatively small number of orders which are not yet billed, then scanning the index on `order_nr` might still be preferable to doing a full table scan.

So, the answer to your question #1 is that no, there is no separate index for `billed`, but rather the index on `order_nr` only can be used for records which have `billed` set to false.  And for #2, yes, a second index on `billed is not true` could be used assuming few records are unbilled.  However, even your current index might even be used as is.