# How BTree boolean index would look like in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, b-tree

I know some basics of BTree data structure, but I want to know how actual data is referenced in pgsql. Let's take `boolean` for example, if we only have two values in a simple BTree (`true`/`false`) - it is obvious, we would just have two nodes (actually one node with two values, but let's talk super simple), but in pgsql we are also storing references to the actual data. How would such an index look like in pgsql structurally?

Would it be like two nodes (for true/false) with some list of references to the actual rows, or would it be like head with `false`, and two linked lists attached to it (false for left and true for right or something like that)?

This question might be very stupid, but I could not find anything useful on google.

Comment: PostgreSQL 13+ implements [btree index deduplication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/btree-implementation.html#BTREE-DEDUPLICATION), so the amount of duplicated index entries are significantly reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A B-tree index has *one entry per table row*. So if your table has 100 million rows, the index will have 100 million entries. This is mitigated to some degree by [index de-duplication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-implementation.html#BTREE-DEDUPLICATION), introduced in v13.

It may be that a GIN index would be smaller (requires extension `btree_gin`), but it would be more expensive to modify. The GIN index would only have two entries, but each would have a large [posting tree](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-implementation.html).

Very often, an index on a `boolean` column [is not useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42972924/6464308).